# How do I resolve error DataGridView/Label1 is not declared?

Tags: add-in, arcgis-explorer

' set the active display
        Dim disp As ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Mapping.MapDisplay = ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.Application.ActiveMapDisplay

```
    ' define the item that selected by user
    Dim SelItem As ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.SelectedItemsCollection = ESRI.ArcGISExplorer.Application.Application.SelectedItems

    ' define the name of selected item
    Dim SIName As String

    ' define a featurelayer for selected item
    Dim FLitem As FeatureLayer

    ' get the name of user selected item
    SIName = SelItem.Item(0).ToString()

    'display the name on the label
    Label1.Text = SIName

    ' find the featurelayer that has the name which equals to the one user selected
    FLitem = disp.Map.FindByName(SIName)

    ' create a new bindtable and fill it with featurelayer's table
    Dim FLbind As TableBindingAdapter
    FLbind = New TableBindingAdapter(FLitem.Table)
    FLbind.Fill()

    ' using the datagridview to show the bindtable which is the selected rows
    DataGridView1.DataSource = FLbind
```